# How to port forward my D-Link DSL-2730U?

Tags: router, dsl

I cant find option to port forward my router.when i enter router setting page i see port mapping option like in the image.
[image]

Comment: There are instructions at [How to open a port on the D-Link DSL-2730U](https://portforward.com/d-link/dsl-2730u/) complete with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Click on the ADVANCED tab and select VIRTUAL SERVER.

Step 2: Check the box beside the rule to enable the rule. For pre-defined applications, use the Application Namedropdown menu and click on the arrow button next to the dropdown menu to auto-fill the appropriate field. For non pre-defined applications not specified in the router, please enter the desired port.

Step 3: Select the computer or device from the list of DHCP clients in the Computer Name dropdown menu or manually enter the IP address of the device you want to open the specified port for.

Step 4: Click on Save Settings.

Secondly,

Generally in D-LINK routers there is a **DMZ** option by which you can achieve port forwarding functionality.

Comment: But there is no virtual server option

Comment: isn't there any advanced tab at the top..?

Comment: Yes.it is the advanced tab screenshot I posted.There is a network tools option in advanced tab.With sub options IGMP proxy and UPnP

Comment: Try Advanced Setup -> NAT -> Virtual Server

Comment: No NAT option.I searched completly.No virtual server option

Comment: Use manual [link] (http://setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dsl-2730u/manual-1648.pdf) of Dlink dsl-2730u model as mentioned by you.

Comment: My router settings page is different from that given in manual